# await Firebase.InitializeApp() do not working

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-dependencies

In the run console

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:6400/pR_lm1UHzmA=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter ( 5558): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(null-error, Host platform returned null value for non-null return value., null, null)
E/flutter ( 5558): #0      FirebaseCoreHostApi.optionsFromResource (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart:248:7)
E/flutter ( 5558): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5558): #1      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:89:25)
E/flutter ( 5558): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5558): #2      Firebase.initializeApp (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:43:31)
E/flutter ( 5558): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5558): #3      main (package:ncc_apps/main.dart:8:3)
E/flutter ( 5558): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 5558):       
void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

`when i remove await .. its working. what should i do?

firebase integrate properly.`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to initialize Firebase on your project using [Firebase CLI.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android)

You can start with `firebase init`, after Firebase setup you will get `firebase_options.dart` which contains your project configuration, your main function will be like

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,// --<<
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these dependencies in your `pubspec.yaml` file

```
  firebase_core: ^2.21.0
```

then inside `main.dart` file

```
void main() async {
  //initialize firebase
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

if you are setting firebase for push notifications add these 2 also in `pubspec.yaml`

```
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.3
  flutter_local_notifications: ^16.1.0
```

Then finally, Install FlutterFire CLI from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#setup_update_cli

then open terminal and use command below and follow instruction

```
flutterfire configure
```

this will generate firebase_options.dart file.

Also to implement push notifications you can add this code (create new file firebase_api.dart)

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';

final _localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

//this function is used for handleing background notifications for Android,
Future<void> handleBackgroudMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('Title: ${message.notification?.title}');
  print('Body: ${message.notification?.body}');
  print('PayLoad: ${message.data}');
}

final androidchannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
    'high_importance_channel', 'High Importance Notifications',
    description: 'This channel is used for important notification ',
    importance: Importance.defaultImportance);
// Function for Sending to selected page from notifications
void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
  if (message == null) {
    return;
  }
}

Future initLocalNotification() async {
  const android = AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_launcher');
  const iOS = DarwinInitializationSettings();
  const settings = InitializationSettings(android: android, iOS: iOS);
  await _localNotifications.initialize(settings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {
    final message = RemoteMessage.fromMap(jsonDecode(payload as String));
    handleMessage(message);
  });
  final platform = _localNotifications.resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>();
  await platform?.createNotificationChannel(androidchannel);
}

Future initNotifications() async {
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, badge: true, sound: true);

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then(handleMessage);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroudMessage);
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
    final notification = message.notification;
    if (notification == null) {
      return;
    }

    _localNotifications.show(
      notification.hashCode,
      notification.title,
      notification.body,
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          androidchannel.id,
          androidchannel.name,
          channelDescription: androidchannel.description,
        ),
      ),
      payload: jsonEncode(message.toMap()),
    );
  });
}

//function for firebase and asking for persmission of notifications,
void setupPushNotifications() async {
  final fcm = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  await fcm.requestPermission();
  final token = await fcm.getToken();
  print("Token : $token");

  fcm.subscribeToTopic("ALL");

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroudMessage);
  initNotifications();
  initLocalNotification();
}
```

and in main.dart file
make you widget stateful (if not) and then use init method for using this code,

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    // initializing push notifications service (ask for permissions)
    setupPushNotifications();
    super.initState();
  }
```